# Accepting a LinkedIn request while actively in the hiring process

Tags: interviewing, linkedin

I am currently in the middle to end stages of the interviewing process.  I have had F2F meetings with all the appropriate parties I am aware of.

Today I received a LinkedIn request from the corporate recruiter that I am reluctant to accept while still employed at my current company.

I am currently connected to my manager and team members, and I would not want them to see a notification from a new connection I have made with a recruiter from a specific company ( not a general recruiter ).

- Am I being overly cautious or is there a real risk of raising questions by my current manager as I think there is?
- Doesn't it seem strange that an in house recruiter I just met would send me a LinkedIn request before the hiring process has ended ( for better or worse )?

Comment: You can turn off those notifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have a legitimate concern. If they're curious about whether you're in the market, they most certainly could look for it. Also, LinkedIn sends out notifications like "Soandso has a connection you might know" which they could receive.

Just hold off on accepting it, it's not like you're rejecting it.  If you're actually asked about it, tell the truth that you didn't want the connection to be seen while we're in the process.

As to your second question, it isn't strange at all. If things don't work out there, maybe they would at a later date and/or maybe you know someone looking that this company could use.